# Create Thumbnails for Uploaded Images

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, thumbnails, image-uploading

I have an asp.net mvc app where I am able to upload multiple images at once and that works fine, but I have an issue with creating thumbnail images out of the originals.

Here's the code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveUploadedFile()
        {
            bool isSavedSuccessfully = true;
            string fName = "";

            try
            {
                foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
                {
                    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];

                    fName = file.FileName;

                    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        var originalDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(string.Format("{0}Images", Server.MapPath(@"\")));

                        string pathString = Path.Combine(originalDirectory.ToString(), "Gallery");
                        string pathString2 = Path.Combine(originalDirectory.ToString(), "Gallery\\Thumbs");

                        //var fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                        bool exists = Directory.Exists(pathString);
                        bool exists2 = Directory.Exists(pathString2);

                        if (!exists)
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);

                        if (!exists2)
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString2);

                        var path = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", pathString, file.FileName);

                        file.SaveAs(path);

                        //WebImage img = new WebImage(file.InputStream);
                        WebImage img = new WebImage(fileName);
                        //if (img.Width > 1000)
                        img.Resize(100, 100);
                        img.Save(pathString2);

                    }

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                isSavedSuccessfully = false;
            }

            if (isSavedSuccessfully)
            {
                return Json(new { Message = fName });
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { Message = "Error in saving file" });
            }
        }
```

So basically `file.SaveAs(path);` is the last line that works and I actually save the images, but after that line I try to create and save thumbs but it does not work (I do get the `Thumbs` folder created before though).

I also get the `Error in saving file` response but that is because I am trying to create and save the thumbs, if I remove that then I don't get it, and I do not know how to return the actual error to actually see what the error is.

Comment: Maybe because `pathString2` in `img.Save(pathString2);`  has value "Gallery\\Thumbs" and you forget to add filename to patch. Try to set breakpoint in `catch` and see which an exception is thrown.

Comment: It's null. Why would it have that value instead of the full path which I assign here string pathString2 = Path.Combine(originalDirectory.ToString(), "Gallery\\Thumbs"); ? And I don't understand "forget to add filename to patch", please provide an example.

Comment: pathstring2 has full and correct path, I just checked on a breakpoint.

Comment: I think the problem is I am not passing what I am supposed to pass to `WebImage img`, because the breakpoint doesn't catch after that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is this:

```
var path2 = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", pathString2, file.FileName)

WebImage img = new WebImage(file.InputStream);
img.Resize(250, 250);
img.Save(path2);
```